# unable to run php project on xampp localhost

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am using xampp for my project.I have copied the file to htdocs and imported database to Xampp.but whenever I am trying to run the code it is not working. showing : localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
how to fix this. I have used this project once before. It worked prfectly. for some reason I deleted the project. I need this to work again. how to fix this? or there is anything alternative to this?

I unistalled xampp and installed again. It is showing same issue.